# Blender vertices not selectable

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, faces

I am using Blender 2.9 and I am trying to select some mesh on the back of my mesh's head.
For some reason, I can't select these faces or their edges and vertices at all in edit mode. I tried removing the mirror modifier and opening Blender again, but I can still not move these specific faces. The rest of the mesh is movable and is working fine.
Is there any way I can fix this? (because I really don't want to model this character all over again).[image: the ones that I circled are the faces that are not moving]

Comment: Most likely the vertices are occluded by overlapping faces. Press Z and select wireframe.

Comment: hello maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @susu I tried that but there are no overlapping faces or vertices. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: I think it's due to a bug that we have seen in latest version, press Alt H and it works again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hidden vertices. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
to unhide them.

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked!